# .ppm image mirrored is upside down and low quality

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, file, ppm

I have this program that should mirror a `.ppm` image.

however, it produces an upside down mirrored image. how can I prevent it from flipping the image upside down?

code:

```
takePPM = input("Enter the pmm file name: ")
try:
    openFile = open(takePPM, "r")
    readFile = openFile.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
    exit(1)
lists = []
for row in readFile[3:]:
    lists.append(row.split())

#convert each list in lists to lists of 3-tuples
target = []
for list in lists:
    target.append([tuple(list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(list),3)])
revList = []
for i in reversed(target):
    revList.append(i)

string = ''
for row in revList:
    for pixel in row:
        for value in pixel:
            string += value + ' '
    string+='\n'


newFile = open("Mirror_" + takePPM, "w")
newFile.write((readFile[0]))
newFile.write((readFile[1]))
newFile.write((readFile[2]))
newFile.write(string)
```

input:
[image]

expected output:
[image]

what I get:

[image]

Comment: Why did you remove all the `import` statements and shebang  thereby making your code unrunnable? Don't you want people to help you? If you are posting questions related to images, you should post your input and expected output images. Treating images as lists of pixels that you iterate over with `for` loops is nearly always fundamentally flawed in Python.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not sure, but I don't think I can use imports, as it as an assignment. I will posting the expected and actual output

Answer (score 1):

Well, mirroring across the horizontal is also mirroring. :-)

It looks like you are assuming that there will be one line in the input file for each row of pixels. This is dangerous; there is no guarantee that this will be the case.

Anyway, if your assumption holds, then `lists` will contain a list of triplets for each row. You then reverse the order of these lists, rather than reversing the order of the triplets within each row!

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to python and this is the first time working with PMM images. without using imports is there a better approach to mirroring the image? and yes I only want a horizontal mirroring but I also get vertical one